# Print unique value for keys

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an array of dicts like this:

```
    {
    "album_image" = "BauerOVTDDVD.jpg";
    "album_title" = "Zuid-Afrika, Om Van Te Dromen";
    "album_year" = 2005;
    "track_duration" = xxx;
    "track_title" = "Ik Neem Voor Jou De Laatste Trein";
},
    {
    "album_image" = "BauerOVTDDVD.jpg";
    "album_title" = "Zuid-Afrika, Om Van Te Dromen";
    "album_year" = 2005;
    "track_duration" = xxx;
    "track_title" = "Als De Avond Voor Ons Is Gevallen";
},
    {
    "album_image" = "BauerOVTDDVD.jpg";
    "album_title" = "Zuid-Afrika, Om Van Te Dromen";
    "album_year" = 2005;
    "track_duration" = "3'26";
    "track_title" = "'n Handje Vol Geluk";
},
    {
    "album_image" = "BauerOVTDDVD.jpg";
    "album_title" = "Zuid-Afrika, Om Van Te Dromen";
    "album_year" = 2005;
    "track_duration" = "3'22";
    "track_title" = "'n Klein Sterretje";
}
```

So there's a different track_title for each track title. Some of these track titles share an album. I only want to print unique album titles. This is the data I have to work with. Should i create a new dict with just album titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the album title, you can use an NSSet for that.

```
NSMutableSet *titles = [NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[trackArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   [titles addObject:[object objectForKey:@"album_title"]];
}];
[titles release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a set of the album titles:

```
NSArray *albumTitlesWithDuplicates = [sourceArray valueForKey:@"album_title"];
NSSet *uniqueAlbumTitles = [NSSet setWithArray:albumTitlesWithDuplicates];
```